# Multer - Cannot Read Property "path" of Undefined

Tags: node.js, image, ejs, multer

I'm trying to upload a single image to mongo using multer but I keep getting this error while trying to access the image path like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
at router.post (D:\Workspace\AdminBootstrap\routes\admin_index.js:74:29)
```

Here's my code to upload the image:

```
router.post('/add-category', uploads.single('category_image'), (req, res) => {

let title = req.body.title;
console.log('Category Title:\t' + title);
let slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
let catImage = req.file.path; // error occurs here 

console.log(catImage);

let category = new Category({
    title: title,
    slug: slug,
    image: catImage
});

category.save()
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            console.log('Saved Category:\t' + result);
            res.redirect('/admin/home');
        }
    })
    .catch(errors => {
        console.error('Error Saving Category:\t' + errors);
    });


});
```

Here's my template:

```
<label>Upload Image</label>
                                <input name="category_image" class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" id="selImg"  onchange="showImage.call(this)">
                                <img src="#" id="imgPreview" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px">
```

Can anyone explain to me why the path is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is throwing an error because "file" is not defined inside "req" object.
It is probably defined in "req.body" object. Use

> console.log(req.body)

to confirm.
Since title is defined on "req.body", "file.path" also should be defined on the same object.

Comment: I should change to req.body.file.path? Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: Yes, req.body should contain file.path. If not then, see how you are setting variables in the form.

Comment: I have tried req.body.file.path and it didnt work. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes. What is the output of console.log(req.body)? Please upload the code from ejs files.

Comment: Ok. While posting with the image form, you have to set file.path variable like you set title, it won't be set automatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate, as in sample snippet?

Answer (score 0):

While setting up your HTML, your form  should have an attribute of 
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`
This will save your file in the path variable