# cant save a file after uploading multer

Tags: javascript, multer

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">
<input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatarinput" onchange="readfichier()"> 
<button type='submit'>Save</button>
</form>
```

**SERVER**

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);

    fs.rename(req.file.path, 'uploads/'+req.file.originalname, function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
          console.log('renamed complete');
    });

    res.end('Success');
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

I got this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Comment: can you please define more about your code

Comment: what else do you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use a disk storage engine to take full control on storing files to disk.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null,file.fieldname+'-'+Date.now()+'.'+file.mimetype.split('/').reverse()[0]);
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Now, define your route and add multer as a middleware.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);

    fs.rename(req.file.path, 'uploads/'+req.file.originalname, function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
          console.log('renamed complete');
    });

    res.end('Success');
})
```

This much is described very well in previous answers as well. But the thing you're missing is to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into your HTML form. Read more about why we need to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatarinput" onchange="readfichier()"> 
<button type='submit'>Save</button>
</form>
```

I hope this solves all your issues. If not, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208813/multer-cannot-read-property-path-of-undefined).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the only code you have.

first  you have to define multer as middleware of an your api

then you have to told your multer that where you want to store your image
I guess it's in your disk

so on your server code looks like this

```
var multer = require('multer');  
var storage = multer.diskStorage({  
   destination: function (req,file,cb){  

       cb(null, './uploads')  
    },
    filename: function (req,file,cb){
        cb(null,file.fieldname+'-'+Date.now()+'.'+file.mimetype.split('/').reverse()[0]);
    },
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage}); 



app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);

    fs.rename(req.file.path, 'uploads/'+req.file.originalname, function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
          console.log('renamed complete');
    });

    res.end('Success');
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem has not gone anywhere

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
/

the problem is on line 'fs.rename(....)'